# how do i automatically pull code from master to fork in azure repos using azure devOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I was trying to pull the code from master to fork repository automatically through the azure pipeline. If any one know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [fork azure repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#create-the-fork) and want to automatically sync the Fork repo using VSTS Git, please follow  below steps.

1. Supposed the url of original repo is [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/test](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_git/test), and the url of forked repo is [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/test_fork](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_git/test_fork).
2. If you click "**Clone**" button in test repository, you will see below panel.
   [image]
3. Clicking "**Generate Git Credentials**" button will show the following panel.
   [image]
   So we can use command `git remote add upstream https://username:password@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/test` to specify it as the upstream of test_fork repo in script.
4. Now creating a build pipeline using [Microsoft-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software), setting the **test_fork** as the source.
   [image]
5. Adding the [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with below script.

```
git remote add upstream https://username:password@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/test
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
git push -f origin HEAD:master
```

6. Queuing a new build and it will succeed to sync the test_fork repo using VSTS Git.
7. You can also [configure schedules for this pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic). Now everything is done.
8. If you use GitHub repo, please refer to this [thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/1607) for guidance.